# Make NewForm.aspx Viewable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want people to be able to submit information using "NewForm," but I don't want them to see any of the information that is saved in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for a few pages on our site by using an html link directly to the New Item form. You can find this address by opening the New Item form in a browser and copying the URL. By changing the "source" portion of the link, you can specify the webpage that you want to load when the form is submitted, rather than have it default to the list contents.
Example:

```
<a href="#"('http://sharepoint/subsite/Lists/sharepoint_list/Item/newifs.aspx?List=6e75d4dd%2D7d05%2D40aa%2D9328%2Dd0ffdc20d4ac&Source=http://sharepoint/home');">My Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want users to submit information using the form but they should be able to see the display form, edit form and the views of the list. You will have to create a list workflow to set permission on list item. Users will have contribute permission in the list. So, they will be able to submit information. Once they submit information, list workflow will be triggered and the workflow will modify permission for the list item granting only intended users access.

Comment: I want a user to be able to submit data with Newform, but I don't want them to be able to see the other data in the list beside their own.

Answer (score 0):

You can set item level permission to achieve this.

Follow below steps:

1. Open your list
2. Go-to list settings
3. Click on advanced settings
4. Under the item level permissions select option that says "Read items that were created by the user"
5. Click OK

Done

Now users will be able to see items in the list that are created by them only and other items will not be visible to them.